# rsync doesn't resolve target symlink to directory

Tags: rsync, symbolic-link

I'm using `ssh` to connect to a remote machine. In my home directory there, I created a symlink to a mounted directory, as you can see below:

```
username@hostname:~$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username users 69 Jan 21 09:09 mysymlink -> /media/some/mounted/target/directory/
```

If I try to run the `rsync` command below on my main machine, it does not resolve the symlink in the destination path and wants to create that directory instead of following the link to the existing directory:

```
~$ rsync -av --progress /home/bytecommander/EclipseProjects -e ssh username@hostname:/home/username/mysymlink
username@hostname's password: 
sending incremental file list
EclipseProjects/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/home/username/mysymlink/EclipseProjects" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***

sent 36,368 bytes  received 2,451 bytes  15,527.60 bytes/sec
total size is 39,039,765  speedup is 1,005.69
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
```

I already tried to add the options below to `rsync`, one at a time, but without any success:

```
    -l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
    -L, --copy-links            transform symlink into referent file/dir
        --copy-unsafe-links     only "unsafe" symlinks are transformed
        --safe-links            ignore symlinks that point outside the tree
    -k, --copy-dirlinks         transform symlink to dir into referent dir
    -K, --keep-dirlinks         treat symlinked dir on receiver as dir
    -H, --hard-links            preserve hard links
```

How can I tell `rsync` that `mysymlink` is a link it should follow when resolving the destination path?